# freeing session variables

Tags: php, session

In our website, we have applied lots of session variables. After setting, we shall unset them to free the server resources.

Apart from unset each session one by one, would there be any function that can check a website  that has session variables not being unset yet?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [`session_destroy();`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php)

```
session_start();

// Unset all of the session variables.
$_SESSION = array();

// If it's desired to kill the session, also delete the session cookie.
// Note: This will destroy the session, and not just the session data!
if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );
}

// Finally, destroy the session.
session_destroy();
?>
```

Also unset the cookie created by the session!

Answer (score 3):

To unset a single record, use

```
unset($_SESSION['varname']);
```

To clear a full session, use

```
session_destroy();
```

A session is removed automatically, when it is not accessed for a while ([configurable via php.ini](http://php.net/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-probability)). Because of this it is not required to remove orphaned session data yourself.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with `session_destroy()`;

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php